# Translucifying chemical?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I was recently shown an object and asked if it was a chestnut. It looked like a regular horse chestnut except instead of an opaque brown surface, the entire nut was slightly translucent, in similarity to dark amber, and with an almost oily texture to the surface.

Is there a chemical that this supposed chestnut could have possibly been dipped in, to give it this translucence?

Apologies if this question is incorrectly tagged, if so, re-direction most appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a photo. Can it be just a core of a chestnut in epoxy resin imitating the shell? There is a recent trend of making low-cost jewelry with environmental and natural object captured with epoxide.

Comment: 3D printed plastic chestnut? Saw it open and put it under a microscope, then you'll know. It might be possible to chemically modify an actual chestnut, but not by just dipping it into sth., more like boiling it in different chemicals at elevated pressure for days.